# Combined hypergeometric distribution of exclusive sets

Tags: distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

Given the following:

- a set of numbers, 1 to 20
- four sets of five numbers from the set above (each number used once)
- a draw of five different numbers from the first set

How would I determine the probability that (at least) 1/2/3/4/5 number(s) will match in any one of the four sets?

To put it another way, each number drawn will be in one of the four sets. How would I determine the probability that (at least) 1/2/3/4/5 number(s) from those drawn will be in the same set?

I am not well-versed in the language of statistics and was not able to find a similar question answered here or elsewhere. If this question proves to be a duplicate, I will happily remove it. In any case, the community's input would be greatly appreciated.